# How to repeat value of array in Flutter

Tags: arrays, dart, flutter, repeater

I'm iOS Developer and new for Flutter. In the Swift language If we want to repeat the same value for a specific time in the Array.

**Ex.**

If In the Array I want to repeat **0** for **5** times then I can do by one line of code like below.

```
let fiveZeros = Array(repeating: "0", count: 5)
print(fiveZeros)
// Prints "["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]"
```

[init(repeating:count:) function used.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init)

So I'm looking for any function or code that works in Flutter.

I do googling but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you share the use case where you need this repeating function?

Comment: actually I'm just making demo app for larnning purpose where I want to do select and unselect ListTile

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can easily find answer from official document of the Flutter.

Comment: I think you should keep it, this is still useful for new developer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In dart you can use the `filled` factory of `List`.

```
final list = List.filled(5, 0);
print(list);  //-> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

See more in the [list docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: Yeah! got expected output. Thanks for improving my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Dart 2.3.0 you can use conditional and loop initializers, so for your case it should be:

```
var fiveZeros = [for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 0];
```

Everything becomes much flexible and powerful when you want to initialize by expression, not just constant:

```
var cubes = [for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) i * i * i];
```

is the same as [0, 1, 8, 27, 64].

Conditional elements are also essential taking into account the possibility to build a list of widgets where some of them depend on the state or platform.

More details [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3f477a6218654f377b863f0d831c2334b20e45db/CHANGELOG.md#230)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ***filled*** method like what @Edman answered. I just want to add one more way by using ***generate***

```dart
final list = new List.filled(5, 0);
print(list);

final list1 =  new List.generate(5, (index) {
  return 0;
});
print(list1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***List.generate*** method.

```
var list = List.generate(5, (i) => 'Z');
```